# jsp:include - An exception occurred processing JSP page

Tags: jsp

I could not find any specific thread for this issue, sorry if this has been asked before.

I am pretty new to JSP and I see the following exception in production which I cannot reproduce locally. I checked that the file `user-management-setup` exists.

```
stackTrace[0]="org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception 
occurred processing JSP page [/WEB- 
INF/jsp/app/generic/admin/instance/settings/user-management.jsp] at 
line [1061]1058:     <div id="appHelp">1059:     <%-- Don't XSS escape 
include tags. These attributes aren't rendered on the page and will 
break1060:                              if any part of the "page" 
attribute has special characters --%>1061:       <jsp:include 
page="/app/${app.name}/${instance.id}/setup/help/user-management- 
setup"/>1062: 1063:     </div>1064: Stacktrace: at
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException 
(JspServletWrapper.java:584)    at 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service 
(JspServletWrapper.java:466)    at 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile 
(JspServlet.java:386)   at 
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service (JspServlet.java:330)  at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:742)   at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter 
(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The JSP code that is causing the issue:

```
<div class="help-wrap">
  <div id="appHelp">
    <%-- Don't XSS escape include tags. These attributes aren't rendered on the page and will break if any part of the "page" attribute has special characters --%>
    <jsp:include page="/app/${app.name}/${instance.id}/setup/help/user-management-setup"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

Also verified that when `app.name` and `instance.id` are invalid or the file does not exist, I get a different error (something like - Resource not found ...) that is different than `An exception occurred processing JSP page`

Comment: You say the file user-management-setup exists, but are you sure the values of your two expressions (app.name and instance.id) are correct?

Comment: Yes, i did check the use case when the file is missing or app.name or instance.id is invalid. I ended up getting a Resource not found error. Not sure what is triggering `An exception occurred processing JSP page`. I also updated the question to include this detail.